# Popup left Menu in Windows Store Apps

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

Can you give sample code or reference tutorial?

I develop  simple windows tab version ,How to create left menu list in widows store app.

I need this format

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a metro way, however you can do this in this manner:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnsDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnsDefinitions>

<!-- menu -->
<ListView Grid.Column="0"/>

<GridView Grid.Column="1"/>
<!-- products -->

</Grid>
```